# Remote desktop to Mac with broken graphics card

Tags: remote-desktop, apple-remote-desktop

We have a mac with a broken graphicscard (Lots of stripes etc.)

Is there some way to run it remotely without being disturbed by the graphics card?

This is a iMac G5 (PowerPC with everything in the screen).

The question is more for apps than the whole desktop.

Comment: Can I bypass the graphics card with  X-Windows?

Comment: I have posted a related question about the X solution:

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74331/osx-as-x-windows-server

Answer (score 2):

Screen Sharing can be enabled via the terminal : **sudo sh -c "/bin/echo -n enabled > /Library/Preferences/com.apple.ScreenSharing.launchd"**

I have had the AppleVNC service freak out because it couldn't determine the clients screen resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Enable Desktop Sharing and use a VNC client to connect to it.

The VNC client built into OS X itself is very good and give good updates, so use that if you use another Mac for this.

Comment: Takk
I have tried with Teamviewer (from Windows), and we still had the stripes.  Is using VNC or doing it from a Mac somehow different.

Comment: Yes.  You need to use Desktop Sharing.

Comment: I also see the graphics card problems remotely :-(

Comment: Interesting.  I would guess it is a software problem and not a hardware problem, then.  Can you boot of the installation media and see if the problem persists?

Comment: Its a kind of problem common in G5, related to damages to the graphics card:

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3992999?start=0&tstart=0