# OS X as X Window Server

Tags: macos, xquartz, remote.app

Is it possible to serve Mac applications like iPhoto over a network to X Window clients?

---

Our problem is that a broken Graphics card is causing a lot of stripes etc on the screen.
Other remote solutions doesn't circumvent the problem.

This is a G5 PowerPC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it isn't. iPhoto and nearly every application on OS X don't run under X11 environment. They have no idea about X11 and cannot be transmitted via X11. Besides, the server component of X-Window runs on the computer whose display is used. You are actually looking for a way to make iPhoto transmit its appearance to a different window server.